# Analysing each commit of a GitHub Repo with SonarQube

Tags: github, deep-learning, sonarqube

I want to analyize several github repos using SonarQube. But i want to analyize each commit individually and see how each commit changed the output of the sonarqube.

Normally i can do this by building and evaluating every commit individually but this takes a lot of unnecessary time because it evaluates the whole program again but i only want to see how it effected the parts that are changed on that commit. Is there a cheap way to do this?

I checked the Sonar GitHub integration but there was no tool that i can use.